# 401 Unauthorized calling my Azure Rest API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a Rest API using controllers, etc, hosted in Azure that has been working for some time. I want to secure the various methods. I added the API App (.NET core) to the App Registrations, and also added the javascript client app to App Registrations. I believe I'm initializing everything in startup.cs in the REST Api OK. I added [Authorize] to one of the methods. I used a simple javascript example which calls myMSALObj.loginPopup, and gets back a token which I then add to the Authorization header and make a fetch call. When I call, I see HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized in the log stream for my App Service.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this to get more specifics about what is wrong?

Also, a related question: in App Registrations, Api Permissions, how does one correlate the API permission name with the method in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in front of the method in the controller
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "My.Scope" })]